# Objective-c: start app with second view with a navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, view, navigationbar

I'm creating an App for Ipad, I created 3 views with a navigation bar but I would to start my application not in first but in second view, what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UINavigationController) with an initial navigation stack via `setViewControllers:animated:`.

```
// in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController new] autorelease];

UIViewController *first = [[MyFirstViewController new] autorelease];
UIViewController *second = [[MySecondViewController new] autorelease];
NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first, second, nil];

[navigationController setViewControllers:controllers animated:NO];

...
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

Comment: where I should write this method? In my first class I have (first view) an IBAction: MoveToNextView where I call my second view and in my second view the same thing. Also I have in APPdelegate  [window addSubview: navController.view]; then, what can I do?

Comment: where I must declare MyFirstViewController and MySecondViewController? it say "use of undeclared identifier MyFirstViewController" and also for the second

Comment: it's ok, I mistake the import of "FirstViewController.h" and "SecondViewController.h", and now my application starts in second view but there is a problem: the back button to return in first view hasn't first view title but its name is "back"...and when I go in first view I can't go in second View because there isn't a button to go in second view...How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Initialise your navigation controller on startup programmatically with 2 controllers already in stack:

```
FirstViewController *first = ...//create controller
SecondViewController *second = ...//create controller

[navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:first, second, nil]
                                animated:NO];
```

Or alternatively you can make your 1st controller push the second one on startup - see Apple's [DrillDownSave](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DrillDownSave/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007800-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) sample for that technique.

Comment: it's ok, I mistake the import of "FirstViewController.h" and "SecondViewController.h", and now my application starts in second view but there is a problem: the back button to return in first view hasn't first view title but its name is "back"...and when I go in first view I can't go in second View because there isn't a button to go in second view...How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Follow somesteps as:

1.open the `MainWindow.xib` in resource folder or bundle.

2.click on Tool and open `Inspector` >> choose `attribute` >> `NIB Name`-set here your view name from drop down list >> `identity` in inspector(from upper tabs) >> choose `class` -set here your view name again from drop down list.

3.Open `appdelegate.m` file
change here the view controller as : `fileviewcontrollername *viewController;`
set it's property.

4.in `didFinishLaunching` in `appdelegate.m` add

```
UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];[window insertSubview:navController.view];[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];return YES;
```

5.In `appdelegate.h` file add

@class viewControllername;