# How can i make my application allways start with the second view?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a Web Service application and it has alogin view. I want to make my application's login view come when the first time app is loaded(installed) and after that it must allways start with a second view. How can i make it? In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487315/objective-c-start-app-with-second-view-with-a-navigation-bar) link there are some solutions but i think this isn't what i'm looking for. Since mine is a web servise, mean the content of the second view(which i want to be pushed allways) is fetched from a server(i use [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class for this work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the login view as a modal view which is only presented when needed.

Edit:
This is VERY brief: (I assume that you are using ARC.)

In AppDelegate:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: mySecondViewController];

if (![self isUserLoggedIn]) {
    MyLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[MyLogInViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController: MyLogInViewController animated: YES];
}
[[self window] setRootViewController: [self navigationController]];
```

and in logInViewController:

```
- (void)logInSuccessful {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i have created all the app and just realized this situation. Do i need to change everything now? Or, is there a wey to turn my login view to a 'model'?

Comment: Sorry I meant modal not model. How are the two view presented? UINavigationController?

Comment: This would be ideal, but it depends on how you have the app set up? is it a navigation based app? TabBar based?

Comment: Yes it is a navigation based application. From the connection between the first view and the second view is made over the action that detects the server and brings the data. I mean, when i press button, i save user information data (send a GET to the server and parse the response) after parsing, push the second view

Comment: I would change to a modal view. To get you started look at `UIViewController` documentation. There are methods to present modal view controllers.

Comment: @dasdomI wish you could give a sample code, i have to finish the project tonight and there are a few important points too which look difficult to deal with:)

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunatelly i dont use ARC, but i think i will overcome using this without ARC. Thanks again